# How to make a C or C++ program execute specific tasks every X seconds, but still do other tasks in between?

Tags: c++, c

This is a sample program that I have created to illustrate a problem. It is intended that the program should print (count) the time in seconds since program start (or counter reset) every second and print a string every 10 seconds. Every 90 seconds, a different string should be written to stdout. But this does not work quite as intended, and I'm not sure why.

```
#include <iostream>     // time_t time();
#include <stdio.h>      // printf();
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>     // sleep();

int main(void) {
    time_t task1_time = (time(NULL) + 10);  // Saves the time 10 seconds ahead from now!
    time_t task2_time = (time(NULL) + 90);  // Saves the time 90 seconds ahead from now!

    int seconds = 0;                        // Variable to count seconds.

    while (1) {
        if (time(NULL) >= task1_time) {     // If the time now has caught up with the 10 seconds:
            task1_time = (time(NULL) + 10); // Saves the time additional 10 seconds ahead from now!
            printf("Task 1 executing!\n");  // Prints a string to stdout.
            seconds = 0;                    // Resets the secondcounter.
        }
        else {
            if (time(NULL) >= task2_time) {         // If the time now has caught up with the 90 seconds:
                task2_time = (time(NULL) + 90);    // Saves the time additional 90 seconds ahead from now!
                printf("\nTask 2 executing!\n");   // Prints a string to stdout.
            }
        }
        printf("%d ", seconds);             // Prints to stdout the number of seconds that have been counted.
        seconds = seconds + 1;              // Adds 1 to seconds.
        sleep(1);                           // Wait 1 second.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What happens is that the program runs for 10 seconds without printing. Then, all the following phrase is printed to stdout at once:

"0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Task 1 executing!"

Thereafter nothing happens for another 10 seconds, until the same phrase is reprinted. And so it goes. After about 90 seconds, the following phrase is printed:

"Task 2 executing!"

The strings printed to stdout is supposed to represent more realistic tasks to be performed in a real application. My purpose is to "interrupt" the program every 10th and 90th seconds to perform separate tasks, while the program in general can keep on with other things in between. I have achieved this before with mbed micro-controllers, where so-called "[Tickers](http://mbed.org/handbook/Ticker)" executes such interruptions, but I have not been able to find a Ticker feature available in standard C or C++.

I have also tried another approach by exchanging **sleep(1)** with **wait(1)**, and added this prototype to the code:

```
void wait (int seconds)
{
  clock_t end_wait = (clock() + (seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
  while (clock() < end_wait) {}
}
```

The program behaviour was the same.

I have also studied the answers given at the post [Print message every x seconds [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203292/print-message-every-x-seconds), but it seems to me that these solutions makes the program unable to do anything else than waiting between the intervals.

A couple of questions:
**Q1: Why isn't one integer printed to stdout each second instead of all integers from 10 seconds back in time being printed at the same time?**
**Q2: Will this approach waste unnecessary CPU-power while waiting/sleeping?**

And of course:
**All proposed solutions and code examples will be appreciated.**

Additional information:
Intended operating system: Linux

Comment: for the second "task" I assume you mean to do `task2_time = (time(NULL) + 90);`? Right now you're adding `900`!

Comment: Yes. Obviously, an additional 0 lurked in there. It shouldn't have been there. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: Why isn't one integer printed to stdout each second instead of all
>   integers from 10 seconds back in time being printed at the same time?

The function `printf` uses buffered output. A `fflush(stdout)` would fix this.

> Q2: Will this approach waste unnecessary CPU-power while
>   waiting/sleeping?

Well not the function `sleep`. But the function `wait` that you use would take up CPU cycles while waiting.

If you want to execute some tasks every `n` seconds, you can go for `threads` or `timers`

Comment: Ok. Thank you! Then I'll stick to sleep();. It seems to work ok after implementing fflush(stdout);

Answer (score 6):

The statement

```
printf("%d ", seconds);
```

really prints the time, but it doesn't *flush* it to the output terminal. Add a call to [`fflush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) directly afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

> Q1: Why isn't one integer printed to stdout each second instead of all
>   integers from 10 seconds back in time being printed at the same time?

Because output is buffered. You need to flush it in some way, perhaps using `fflush(stdout)` right after the `printf`.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but you could easily get something like a "tick interrupt" using signals. You have to be careful what functions you call from signals though, they have to be "async-signal-safe".

For example on Linux, which you mentioned you could use `timer_create` and you will get a signal for every "tick" you specify.

Comment: I forgot to say thank you. The fflush(stdout); worked indeed, and solved my problem. But why doesn't the buffer flush by itself in this particular case, while it usually does in other cases? How can you determine when fflush(); has to be called manually?

Comment: It depends on how `stdout` is setup. Typically it is line-buffered for a user-facing devince but not for a file. To be on the safe side, always flush.

Comment: So if I don't use cr (\r), lf (\n) or both, in my printf() statement, I can't expect the buffer to be flushed immediately? Or does that apply only for lf (\n)? Usually my stdout is a terminal emulator, either gnome-terminal or cmd.exe, I rarely use anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Linux user space you can't set up an interrupt as you used to do with your microcontroller with Tickers, because each architecture where Linux runs can be different and handle interrupts in a different way.

You could run a separate thread though, you can use POSIX threads, find a tutorial here:
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html